# Android : What is the correct gradle configuration to use Mockito to support espresso and unit test both?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, android-espresso

I am running couple of tests using Espresso and some tests are plain junit, both tests require mockito.

Wondering how to include mockito correctly to support both , if I use one  of below  configuration other wouldn't work.

1) `testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"`

2) `androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+`

Answer (score 0):

I currently configure and run them in separate build types, because of the dexmaker conflict. Not sure whether it is the intended/correct way or there is a better way of doing it.

So assuming you have already a "debug" build type, define another, i.e. "espresso". Then the build gradle would look like:

```
android {
  ...
  testBuildType 'espresso'
}

...

dependencies {

  ...

  def mockito = "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
  espressoCompile(mockito) {
      exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
  }
  espressoCompile("com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:$dexMakerVersion") {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
  }
  espressoCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:$dexMakerVersion"

  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espressoVersion"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
  androidTestCompile mockito

  testCompile mockito
}
```

When you want to run the tests, you need to call the targeted gradle scripts, i.e. 'testDebug' or 'installEspressoAndroidTest'.

Or within Android Studio, you need to run the espresso tests after switching to "espresso" build variant.

Hope it helps or give you some idea about it.